# To get the repository id from an existing project of Azure DevOps in terraform code

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-devops-rest-api

I need to get the repository id of an existing project to work on that repo. There seems no other way than using Azure DevOps REST API.

I tried to utilize the REST API to get the repo id in my terraform code:

```
data "http" "example" {
  url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.0"

  request_headers = {
    "Authorization" = "Basic ${base64encode("PAT:${var.personal_access_token}")}"
  }
}

output "repository_id" {
  value = data.http.example.json.value[0].id
}
```

It yields error while I was running terraform plan:

```
Error: Unsupported attribute
line 29, in output "repository_id":
29:   value = data.http.example.json.value[0].id
```

I tried also with jsondecode (jq is already installed):

```
resource "null_resource" "example" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "curl -s -H 'Authorization: Bearer ${var.pat}' https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.0 | jq '.value[0].id'"
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
  }
}
output "repo_id" {
  value = "${jsondecode(null_resource.example.stdout).id}"
}
```

That did not work either!!

Azure DevOps REST API works fine, I just cannot fetch the value from the responce into terraform! What would be the right code or can it be done without using REST API!

Thank you!

Comment: "That did not work either!!" is not specific. what exactly is happening? Any errors?

Comment: Thanks! 
│`Error: Unsupported attribute
│ line 25, in output "repo_id":
│  25:   value = "${jsondecode(null_resource.example.stdout).id}"
│ This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named "stdout"`

Comment: What is the exact value of `null_resource.example.stdout`?

Comment: This is the REST API response:

`{"value":[{"id":"3156fa4f-99a3-426e-12f3-2943f2357b16","name":"project-01er","url":"https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/803a2bc6-e3ce-40b9-ab2d-4cccf2dcbca6/_apis/git/repositories/3156fa4f-99a3-426e-12f3-2943f2357b16","project":{"id":"113a2bc6-e3ce-40b9-ab2d-4cccf2dcbca6","name":"project-01er","url":"https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/_apis/projects/113a2bc6-e3ce-40b9-.....`

I need to get the id of 3156fa4f-99a3-426e-12f3-2943f2357b16. I could not get any output of `null_resource.example.stdout` in the terraform.

Answer (score 0):

To proper way to interact with external API and return its output to TF is through [external data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source). TF docs linked provide example of how to use and create such a data source.